# Buscar elemento no repetido de un array

Tags: java

Como crear un programa para buscar el numero que no se repite en un array de numeros pre-ordenado. Por ejemplo, tenemos el siguiente array de numeros:

int array[]= {2, 2, 4, 4, 13, 13, 14, 14, 25, 30, 30};

el cual tendria que regresar el valor 25, siendo el numero que no se repite ninguna vez.

Comment: Buenos días Genaro, bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo que te hagas el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento del sitio y mires [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta, ya que las preguntas que no muestran lo que se ha intentado, normalemente se cierran por "baja calidad".

Comment: Genaro aqui no hacemos los deberes a la gente , si quieres ayuda en algun punto **concreto** comparte el código de lo que tienes hasta el momento

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo puedes saber si un elemento no está repetido? Como damos por supuesto que el array está ordenado, un elemento no repetido es aquel cuyo valor es diferente del valor del elemento anterior y del elemento siguiente.

Para resolver este ejercicio tendrás que hacer un pequeño algoritmo de búsqueda, que mire si el elemento actual es diferente del elemento anterior y del siguiente, en ese caso se debe parar la búsqueda y devolver el elemento que no está repetido. Cómo estás haciendo una búsqueda, tendrás que hacer un bucle que itere sobre el array.

¿Cuántas veces tienes que iterar en el bucle? Tantas como elementos en la lista haya empezando desde el segundo elemento en la lista. Eso sí, si encuentras un elemento repetido tendrás que parar la búsqueda.

¿Qué hay que hacer dentro del bucle? En cada iteración, comparar el elemento actual con el anterior y con el siguiente. En el caso del último elemento del array, solo tendrás que comparar con el elemento anterior. En caso de que encuentres el elemento, el bucle deberá parar y se deberá devolver el valor actual.

Otras consideraciones: Tendrás que considerar qué devolver en caso de que todos los números estén repetidos (devuelves null, -1, tiras una excepción...). Tendrás que considerar también que un array con 0 o 1 elementos no puede tener elementos repetidos, y que un array con 2 elementos puede estar repetido si los dos números son iguales, por lo que solo necesitarás comparar el valor del segundo elemento con el primero.

Intenta hacerlo tú ya que es un ejercicio, genera algo de código y si algo te falla, edita la pregunta con el código que tengas hecho.

Answer (score -1):

Recorre el `array` y usa `.count()` en cada posición. Si la cantidad retornada es igual a 1, entonces es un único elemento.

Si lo quieres optimizar, puedes usar `remove()` y eliminar los elementos repetidos, así no se demora tanto tu código.

Comment: Java no tiene un método .count() ni en los arrays, ni en los enteros ni en las listas de enteros. Tienes size() y length, pero no te van a decir el número de ocurrencias de un elemento en una colección, te van a decir el número de elementos totales en una colección.